# SQL linked server returning error suddenly upon query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server

We are facing error when trying to connect to and execute queries using a linked server. The SQL Server and the Linked Server are able to `ping` and `telnet` each other. Also testing the link returns positive. However, the following error is returned when we execute a query accessing the linked server:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server  returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server  returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server  returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server  returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I'm trying to prove that this is a network issue, but since the communication channel is open and `ping` and `telnet` work, the task fell back in my basket.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried connecting by ip?

Comment: Can you establish a connection from one server to the other using SSMS and run a few simple queries?

Comment: @datagod The result was inconsistent. Some queries execute but some would fail.

Answer (score 3):

This does look like a network issue, as per [this question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45156a48-afa7-4756-a1a3-80ab550e6888/protocol-error-in-tds-stream-error-a-connection-cannot-be-made-ensure-that-the-server-is-running?forum=sqlanalysisservices) the "Protocol error in TDS stream" indicates as such.

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37184/communication-link-failure-for-some-queries-to-linked-server) seems to be a very similar question that was resolved by disabling [TCP Chimney Offload](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/951037/information-about-the-tcp-chimney-offload--receive-side-scaling--and-n) (think link in that question directs to a [veritas article](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH197934) that describes how to do it).

Which may be a quick (and possibly dirty) was of trying to resolve it. If that is not the problem, then it is almost certainly a network problem (maybe a nic problem).

--

*Edit:*

Might be worth making sure the native client is fully up to date (by [updating SQL Server](https://sqlserverupdates.com/), which is no bad thing anyway).

Also, if you're still struggling, add some more information about your environment to your question e.g. OS version, SQL Server version & update level, information about your nics etc.

Comment: This was a network related issue. We have resolved it but have opened up another pandora box.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed network related and the network and data center team finally agreed. Right now, the root cause analysis is ongoing and the first culprit is a malfunctioning NIC on one of the VMs. There is also a DNS issue with one of the Always ON SQL Server Node.

However, we did a failover to another site, and the linked server is running again.